# Python how to automatically set time and timezone in windows enabled

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I have this code to automatically set time and timezone in windows enabled.
with first lines I am making sure that the code has admin privileges but the code runs and gives no error but the changes in registry are not applied.

```
import ctypes
if not ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
    raise Exception("Admin privileges required to modify registry.")
import win32api
import win32con
# Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient
# Define the registry key path and value name
key_path = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient"
value_name = "Enabled"

# Enable the "Set time automatically" feature
win32api.RegSetValueEx(
    win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    key_path + "\\" + value_name,
    0,
    win32con.REG_DWORD,
    1,
)

# Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tzautoupdate
# Define the registry key path and value name
key_path = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tzautoupdate"
value_name = "Start"

# Enable the "Set time zone automatically" feature
win32api.RegSetValueEx(
    win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    key_path + "\\" + value_name,
    0,
    win32con.REG_DWORD,
    1,
)
print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
win32api.RegSetValueEx(
    win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    key_path + "\\" + value_name, # this is incorrect - value names are not appended to key name paths
    0,
    win32con.REG_DWORD,
    1,
)
```

This:

```
regkey = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key_path, 0, win32con.KEY_WRITE)

win32api.RegSetValueEx(regkey, value_name, 0, win32con.REG_DWORD, 1)

win32api.RegCloseKey(regkey)
```

Use the same approach for the other registry key as well.

Comment: I couldnt edit ur answer but fix this to `regkey = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(
    win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    key_path,
    0,
    win32con.KEY_WRITE)`

Comment: btw I my timezone settings are greyed out and I manually tried numbers 1to4 but none of them made it modifiable.

Comment: thank you, I made changes to make it work, yet didnt work